# Unable to reduce cyclomatic complexity in a Factory method without using reflection

Tags: c#, vb.net, design-patterns, reflection, factory-method

In my factory method I use Switch statement to create concrete objects. This results in very high cyclomatic complexity. Here is a sample code:

```
private static UnitDescriptor createUnitDescriptor(string code)
{
     switch (code)
     {
         case UnitCode.DEG_C:
             return new UnitDescriptorDegC();

         case UnitCode.DEG_F:
             return new UnitDescriptorDegF();

         :
         :
         default:
             throw new SystemException(string.format("unknown code: {o}", code);
      }
  }
```

How can I refactor this to reduce cyclomatic complexity? If I use reflection to create objects or something else to build objects is it better than above method?

Comment: In default case try to return a value insted of throwing an exception and try agin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible for you to use a `Dictionary` to remove the `switch` statement entirely:

```
class MyClass
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Func<UnitDescriptor>> dict = new Dictionary<string, Func<UnitDescriptor>>();

    static MyClass()
    {
        dict.Add(UnitCode.DEG_C, () => new UnitDescriptorDegC());
        dict.Add(UnitCode.DEG_F, () => new UnitDescriptorDegF());
        // Other mappings...
    }

    private static UnitDescriptor createUnitDescriptor(string code)
    {
        Func<UnitDescriptor> value;
        if (dict.TryGetValue(code, out value))
        {
            return value();
        }

        throw new SystemException(string.Format("unknown code: {0}", code));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adi... great answer, now I dont have to use reflection :)

Comment: Performance trouble here, as your factory needs to create a new instance of each element in your dictionnary. Worst than that, your dictionnary is mandatory to be a static, meaning all instances you'll create will stay in memory until the end of your code.
I'm currently searching the same solution to your problem without losing time and space optimization, and I don't have found yet.

Comment: @niconoe The created instances are not static - they'll be freed when you're done using them. The only things that will be kept in memory forever are the dictionary and what it holds (the key strings and the value-creating functions).

Comment: @AdiLester You're probably right in c# as I'm not an expert, but I'm trying to solve this puzzle case in PHP where I know this solution can't be used for the reasons I explained. Maybe c# is smarter that way. But you can't deny that you'll lost in time as you'll need to build all instances, running all constructs for them. Depending on the constructors business, it can be heavy...

Answer (score 0):

This question is the 1st result when googling "cyclomatic complexity factory".
The use of a Dictionary greatly reduce the cyclomatic complexity however as pointed out niconoe in PHP using such approach will increase the memory usage because objects are loaded at runtime.

To solve this issue we can use Dictionary + Closures. Objects declared inside a closure are not created until the closure is called.

```
class NotTriggered
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "not triggered\n";
    }

    public function trigger()
    {
        echo "still not triggered\n";
    }

}

class triggered
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "triggered\n";
    }

    public function trigger()
    {
        echo "triggered again\n";
    }

}

function echoHello()
{
    echo "hello\n";
}

function echoWorld()
{
    echo "world\n";
}

$arr = [
    0 => fn() => echoHello(),
    1 => echoWorld(),
    2 => fn() => (new NotTriggered)->trigger(),
    3 => (new Triggered)->trigger(),
];

//output :
//world
//triggered
//triggered again
```

so in a factory method the code could look like this

```
public function createService($serviceName): ServiceInterface
{
    $services = [
        'service1' => fn() => new Service1(),
        'service2' => fn() => new Service2(),
        'service3' => fn() => new Service3(),
    ];

    return $services[$serviceName] ?? throw new \Exception('service not registered');
}
```